# Handling of NULL Values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Please help, on my select top 1 query, i want to prioritize MODIFIED_DATE IS NULL, and if MODIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL then it will refer to `OR a.MODIFIED_DATE < (select max(MODIFIED_DATE)`

```
UPDATE TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS
SET PRIORITY_CD = @COL_SORT, MODIFIED_DATE = getdate(), MODIFIED_BY = 'c3webuser'
FROM
(
    SELECT Top 1 * from TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS a
    WHERE
    a.PARTNER_SYS_ID = @PARTNER_SYS_ID
    AND a.ISO_CNTRY_CD = @COUNTRYCODE
    AND a.PRIORITY_CD = @PRIORITY_CD
    AND a.MODIFIED_DATE IS NULL
    OR a.MODIFIED_DATE < (select max(MODIFIED_DATE) from TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS b where b.PARTNER_SYS_ID = 'DEV0011'
                            AND b.ISO_CNTRY_CD = 'AU' AND b.PRIORITY_CD = 1)

    ORDER BY CREATED_DATE ASC
) TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I infer it is not working as intended ... Did you check operator precedence of "and" and "or" ? Maybe it's enough to introduce a pair of "()" ...

Comment: Just add some  sample data and the expected result. That way we can help you to fix your query or write a better one.

Comment: I have a for loop using c#. I have an array list, Priority_cd column has a value of 1, 2 up to 12. While col_sort value also composes of 1 to 12. Col_sort value will be the value of priority_cd. Array list is stored in c# so each index will go to for loop to update priority_cd. My problem is once priority code has been updated then there is tendency that i have 2 records of  priority cd with the value of 1. I want records to be updated base on the priority cd and col_sort values on my array.